# What is this effect's name? And how would I be able to do it in Sony Vegas?

Tags: video, vegas-pro

I would name this effect a sort of lens flare, but the lens flare tutorials I have seen on YouTube are not what I am looking for... Such as [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xp10GS_XUI)

Anyway, this is the effect I am trying to replicate, as displayed in the Galantis - No Money Music Video

at the following times: 0:17-0:21, 0:27-0:31, 0:35-0:40 and many other places through out the video...

Thank you for any responses I may get :)

---

Kind Regards

Joshua Lochner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search Google for "light leaks". Here's free collection: http://vegasaur.com/free-light-leaks

How to use: Place the desired light leak clip on the track above your video and set track's compositing mode to Screen or Add. Adjust the amount of light by lowering the clip or track opacity. You can also add change luminance or color by adding Levels, Color Balance or Hue/Saturation filters.

Comment: Here is much bigger collection of free light leaks: https://www.cutestockfootage.com/stock-video-footage/category/7830/light-leaks

Tutorial of using them in Sony Vegas is also there: https://www.cutestockfootage.com/tutorials/